# How to hide desktop css from iphone browser?

Tags: iphone, css, browser, safari

I have a web page for which I made two css files, one for desktop browser and another for iphone.
I do it something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" media="screen,projection,print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mobi.css" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" />
```

On a desktop it works fine, but on iphone I Have some strange behavior, it looks like it loads both files and rules conflict with each other. If I comment out second line (main.css) it works fine on iphone.

so how can I hide it? 
thanks

Comment: you should assume that the default css is loaded and then add specific rules in mobi.css that modify/reset main.css - media queries could be an alternative too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution and it is actually quite simple, just need to use media querys. Something like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 480px)' href='css/mobi.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 481px)' href='css/main.css' />

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

We can change width depending on target device. It works fine on iphone (and most of other smartphones) and also works in all desktop browsers apart from our beloved IE:) to fix this issue just add:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" media="all" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

I included **WHOISSTAN**'s php function example from [http://mobiforge.com](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/lightweight-device-detection-php):

```
function is_mobile(){
    $regex_match="/(nokia|iphone|android|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|";
    $regex_match.="htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|";
    $regex_match.="blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|";    
    $regex_match.="symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|";
    $regex_match.="jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220";
    $regex_match.=")/i";        
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE']) or preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}
```

Then I added this within my `<HEAD></HEAD>` tags:

```
<?php
    if(is_mobile()) {
        ?><link rel="stylesheet" href="mobi.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" /> <?php 
    } else { 
        ?> <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> <?php
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use mobile detection in php or another server side script so that the other css is not there at all. here is a place to get a good script

http://detectmobilebrowser.com/

the script needs to be modified a lil. it comes in a `if` statment so if you put it in a function you can return a `true` or `false`. Then you can use it like.

```
if(mobiDetect()){
 <link href="mobiStyle.css" />
}else{
 <link href="style.css" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should let mobi.css apply handheld styles on top of main.css. Also, I guess media should be handheld for mobi.css, and not a bunch of text like you have now.

Comment: The "bunch of text" is a perfectly valid media query.

Comment: Yeah for new browsers, I wasn't sure if iphone meant ONLY iphone specific. IMO equal to devs that used to make ONLY for IE.

Answer (score 0):

Mobile WebKit applies stylesheets with media type of `screen`, because it’s meant to behave like a desktop browser with some UI optimisations for mobile, rather than as a mobile browser.

You might consider serving different HTML to iPhone-like browsers, get around it that way. I don’t think there’s any reliable HTML- or CSS-based way to hide CSS from Mobile WebKit.